# Audio element is disabled (invalid source error)

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I was inserted  4 Audio tags I'm my website and all of them work correctly.

But today every new element that I want to add, doesn't work.

A tested all updated browser... A changed audio file format to mp3, ogg, alaw wave, ulaw wave....but it is not fixed yet. All new audio  elements are disabled and IE  shows "invalid source".

I extracted these files from video files (MP4 and WEMB Type).
I read all posts about this problem but those don`t solve this problem.

this is my code:

```
             <h4>first audio file</h4>
              <!--------------this is working corectly-->
             <audio controls class="form-control ">
                 <source src="/Portal2/content/audio/azami-qozat (1).MP3" type="audio/mp3">
             </audio>
             <audio controls class="form-control ">
                 <source src="/Portal2/content/audio/azami-qozat (2).MP3" type="audio/mp3">
             </audio>
             <audio controls class="form-control ">
                 <source src="/Portal2/content/audio/azami-qozat (3).MP3" type="audio/mp3">
             </audio>

          

          
             <h4>second audio file</h4>
              <!--------this is not working-->
             <audio controls class="form-control ">
                <source src="/Portal2/content/audio/Vashekastegi (2).MP3" type="audio/mp3">
             </audio>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Check the network panel of your dev tools, what does it say about the requests to these files? Try to load these urls directly from your browser's address bar, does it work there? Beware that spaces and cases in URLs can cause issues on some backends.

Comment: please help me!

Comment: @Arshin **(1)** try to avoid `space` in your filenames. Replace spaces with underscore like new name is `Vashekastegi_2.MP3`. **(2)** Make sure file is available `https://www.yoursite.com/Portal2/content/audio/Vashekastegi_2.mp3` should play if you put that in address bar. **(3)** Maybe file is corrupt. Can you make a demo page for us (give link) to see the problem in action?